# Using Chessboard.js to load in pgn and allow users to play through the game with arrow key presses

Tags: javascript, sqlite, chessboard.js

I am trying to program a straightforward feature in which I retrieve a `.pgn` from a sqlite database and load in a chessboard from the `chessboard.js` which allows users to play through that game hitting the arrow keys (left to take back and right to go to the next move).

I was able to set up a board that allows only [legal moves](https://chessboardjs.com/examples#5000).

```
var board = null
var game = new Chess()
var $status = $('#status')
var $fen = $('#fen')
var $pgn = $('#pgn')

function onDragStart (source, piece, position, orientation) {
  // do not pick up pieces if the game is over
  if (game.game_over()) return false

  // only pick up pieces for the side to move
  if ((game.turn() === 'w' && piece.search(/^b/) !== -1) ||
      (game.turn() === 'b' && piece.search(/^w/) !== -1)) {
    return false
  }
}

function onDrop (source, target) {
  // see if the move is legal
  var move = game.move({
    from: source,
    to: target,
    promotion: 'q' // NOTE: always promote to a queen for example simplicity
  })

  // illegal move
  if (move === null) return 'snapback'

  updateStatus()
}

// update the board position after the piece snap
// for castling, en passant, pawn promotion
function onSnapEnd () {
  board.position(game.fen())
}

function takeBack () {
  board.position(game.undo())
}

function updateStatus () {
  var status = ''

  var moveColor = 'White'
  if (game.turn() === 'b') {
    moveColor = 'Black'
  }

  // checkmate?
  if (game.in_checkmate()) {
    status = 'Game over, ' + moveColor + ' is in checkmate.'
  }

  // draw?
  else if (game.in_draw()) {
    status = 'Game over, drawn position'
  }

  // game still on
  else {
    status = moveColor + ' to move'

    // check?
    if (game.in_check()) {
      status += ', ' + moveColor + ' is in check'
    }
  }

  $status.html(status)
  $fen.html(game.fen())
  $pgn.html(game.pgn())
}

var config = {
  draggable: true,
  position: 'start',
  onDragStart: onDragStart,
  onDrop: onDrop,
  onSnapEnd: onSnapEnd
}
board = Chessboard('legalBoard', config)



updateStatus()
```

Followed by the following html code.

```
<div id="legalBoard" style="width: 400px"></div>
<span>Status</span>
<div id="status"></div>
<span>PGN</span>
<div id="pgn"></div>
<span>FEN</span>
<div id="fen"></div>
```

Which creates the following chessboard that indeed allows users to pick up pieces and make legal moves:

[image: legal board]

How do I need to adapt this code to load in a game, and allow users to hit their arrow keys and play through that game?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use @mliebelt/pgn-parser to parse the pgn
   1.1 `import { parse } from '@mliebelt/pgn-parser'`
   1.2 `let moves = parse(my_pgn_string, {startRule: "game"}).moves;`
2. Loop over the moves
3. Use the Chess object to convert the PGN notation to start and end moves:
   3.1 `let move_obj = game.move(moves[i].notation.notation);`
4. Use Chessboard move to display move:
   4.1 `chessboard.move(move_obj.from +'-'+ move_obj.to);`

Comment: PS: It is possible to convert chessboard.js moves to PGN / SAN moves by using chess.move({ from: source, to: target })